# How to redirect output to a text file and the console (cmd) window at the same time?

Tags: windows, command-line, logging, redirection

How can I redirect output to a text file and the console (cmd) window at the same time?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Powershell 2.0 comes with the [`Tee-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347705.aspx) cmdlet which does exactly that. If you're using Windows 7, it comes with Powershell 2.0 installed. If you're using an older version of Windows, Powershell 2.0 is [available for download](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/pages/download-windows-powershell.aspx).

The benefit of Powershell is that it can run the commands that cmd can as well.

Example:

```
dir | Tee-Object -file c:\output\dir.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796476/dos-command-to-display-result-on-console-and-redirect-the-output-to-a-file/796492#796492) for an identical question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796476/dos-command-to-display-result-on-console-and-redirect-the-output-to-a-file)

In summary, find a Win32 port of the Unix `tee` command.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a batch file tool for this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
 SET Append=false 
IF /I "%~1]=="/a" ( SET Append=true & SHIFT )
IF "%~1"== "" GOTO help
IF "%~2"== "" GOTO help
 SET Counter=0 
FOR /F %%A IN ('DIR /A /B %1 2^>NUL') DO CALL :Count "%%~fA"
 IF %Counter% GTR 1 ( SET Counter= & GOTO Syntax ) 
 SET File=%1
 DIR /AD %File% >NUL 2>NUL
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 ( SET File= & GOTO Syntax ) 
 SET Y= 
VER | FIND "Windows NT" > NUL 
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET Y=/Y
 IF %Append%==false  (COPY %Y% NUL %File% > NUL 2>&1) 
 FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A IN ('FIND /N /V ""') DO (
    > CON ECHO.%%B  
        >> %File% ECHO.%%B
 ) 
ENDLOCAL 
GOTO:EOF
 :Count 
SET /A Counter += 1
 SET File=%1 
GOTO:EOF
 :help
 ECHO.
 ECHO Display text on screen and redirect it to a file simultaneously ECHO Usage: some_command ^| TEE.BAT [ /a ] filename 
 ECHO. 
ECHO Where: "some_command" is the command whose output should be redirected
 ECHO "filename" is the file the output should be redirected to
 ECHO /a appends the output of the command to the file,
 ECHO rather than overwriting the file
 ECHO. 
ECHO Made by Wasif Hasan. Nov 2019
Usage: command | tee
```

Usage:

> `command | tee [/a] filename`
>
> [`/a`] will append to the file instead of over writing.

Answer (score -3):

Use Tee-Object to pipe to variable with the -variable switch then use the variable to output to screen how you would like

```
get-aduser -filter * -Properties Name, CanonicalName, LogonWorkstations | where { $_.logonworkstations -match "\D" } | Select Name, CanonicalName, logonworkstations | sort canonicalname | Tee-Object -variable Users | Export-Csv -Path ".\$($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name.split(".")[0])__$(Get-Date -uformat "%Y-%m-%d_%I-%M-%S_%p").csv" -NoTypeInformation

$Users | FL

Clear-Variable Users
```

Comment: Welcome. This question is about the Command Prompt (CMD) not PowerShell.