# How to save ipconfig output to text file when `tee` isn't available on Windows?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, file-transfer

I want to save ipconfig /all to text file.I am on Windows 10.When I try this in cmd

```
ipconfig /all | tee file.txt
```

I got

```
'tee' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

What is Windows alternative for `tee`?

Comment: I suggest removing `powershell` as a tag in your question, as `ipconfig /all | tee file.txt` is a valid PowerShell command and works exactly as you expect it to. `tee` is an alias for `Tee-Object`.

Comment: For what its worth, tee is never needed to save output to a file - that's just so you can see the output _and_ save it to a file.

Comment: Should you wish to output to say display and to file, there is a Windows version of tee called wintee : https://code.google.com/archive/p/wintee/

Comment: @Dimblefeck there are so many tee implementations for Windows like gnuwin32 tee and windows also have a native one in powershell

Comment: so many duplicates: [tee for Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/74127/241386), [How can I both pipe and display output in Windows' command line?](https://superuser.com/q/767680/241386), [How to redirect output to a text file and the console (cmd) window at the same time?](https://superuser.com/q/109953/241386)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows: Command line redirection to text file while also seeing output](https://superuser.com/questions/278115/windows-command-line-redirection-to-text-file-while-also-seeing-output)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try redirection.  Instead of `| tee`, use `> output.txt` e.g.

```
ipconfig /all > output.txt
```

Comment: redirection doesn't work like tee. You need to print the file afterwards like `ipconfig /all > output.txt & type output.txt`, but it still won't behave like tee which outputs immediately

Comment: This question is tagged "cmd.exe" and not "PowerShell".  There is no equivalent for tee in cmd.exe.  There is however, Tee-Object in PowerShell, which has tee as an alias.

Comment: yes, but your answer **doesn't answer what the OP wants**, which is **putting output in both stdout and file**

Comment: The question title specifically states "HOW TO SAVE IPCONFIG OUTPUT TO A TEXT FILE WHEN TEE IS NOT AVAILABLE".  There is no mention in the question title, nor the body, of displaying the content to the screen simultaneously other than a reference to the tee command itself.

Answer (score 19):

`ipconfig /all >>logfile.txt 2>>&1`

The `>>logfile.txt 2>>&1` will redirect both output stream and error stream to a file called logfile.txt that will be created and stored in the current directory. If there is an existing logfile.txt in that directory it will append the output to the end of it.

Comment: Are you **sure** this usage is correct? It looks like nonsense, and it's undocumented in the [Windows i/o redirection documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true). `2>>&1` does not take a file argument. For Powershell, `ipconfig /all *>> logfile.txt` is how you [append all output streams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41148807/699305) to a file.

Comment: Did you mean `ipconfig /all >> logfile.txt 2>&1` perhaps?

Comment: I'm surprised my mistake went without being pointed out for this long, indeed I was a little bit off as I just quickly checked a .bat file I had it in myself and misread it at a glance. I have edited my answer to the correct usage, apologies!

Answer (score 8):

If you install [MSYS2](http://www.msys2.org/) you can use

```
$ ipconfig -all | tee file.txt
```

Note that `/all` has to be written as `-all`.

In my case I get:

```
$ head file.txt

Windows-IP-Konfiguration

   Hostname  . . . . . . . . . . . . : Death-Star
   [..]
```

Comment: While this is not a bad answer, putting MSYS2 in your path has surprising consequences.

Comment: If you don't like MSYS, there's GnuWin32. The `tee` utility is under [GnuWin32 core utils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm).

Comment: @JimB: MSYS wasn't great, so GnuWin32 was a good alternative for it, but MSYS2 has been excellent as far as I've tried it. I do not know of any reason to use GnuWin32 over it.

Comment: @Joshua: What are the consequences? I just put it after the normal stuff and it works fine?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Some of that stuff expects other stuff provided by it to be early in the path. I haven't tried to catalog all the cases but eventually you discover you have two `find` commands that do different things.

Comment: no need for msys2. `powershell -command "ipconfig /all | tee output.txt"` will work if you're in cmd

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc make an answer of your proposal, it is by far and wide the very best solution!